# What are the predictions of Nastradamus on Hinduism?

Tags: astrology

Nastradamus is arguably the most famous astrologer. He was French by nationality, and he lived around 1500 AD.

He is renowned for his prophecies on world events. I know that he made a few predictions on Hinduism.

I want his list of prophecies on Hinduism along with the verse numbers.

Answer (score 1):

> "De l’aquatique triplicité naîtra
> D’un qui fera le jeudi pour sa fête:
> Son bruit, los, regne, sa puissance croîtra,
> Par terre et mer aux Orients tempête"

> From the three water signs will be born a man
> who will **celebrate Thursday as his holiday**.
> His renown, praise, rule and power will grow
> on land and sea, bringing trouble to the East.
> (*Century I, Quatrain 50*)

Thursday is a holiday for only Hindus.

> "Religion du nom des mers vaincra,
> Contre la secte fils Adaluncatif :
> Secte obstinée déplorée craindra
> Des deux blessés par Aleph et Aleph"

> The **Religion of the name of the seas will conquer**
> Against the sect, son of Adaluncatif:
> The stubborn, lamented sect will be afraid
> Of the two wounded by Aleph and Aleph.
> (*Century X, Quatrain 96*)

In geography, one finds the Hind Mahasagar (Indian Ocean). Also, the name "Hindu" itself comes from the name "Sindhu". Sindhu means ocean in Sanskrit. This is the only religion whose name has any connection with the sea. "Adaluncatif" is a word invented by Nastradamus. "Alef and Alef" is often amended to first letters of Hebrew alphabets. Nastradamus had a Jewish root.

Reference for verses -
[Les Propheties by Nastradamus translated by Edgar Leoni](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Propheties)

Answer (score 0):

https://documents.pub/reader/full/hindu-destiny-in-nostradamus-pa-part-1.html

Maybe this book will help you, though part 1 is written , I think it is complete book.

https://holybooks.com/wp-content/uploads/The-Complete-works-of-Nostradamus.pdf meanwhile to confirm passages given in "hindu destiny in nostradamus" you can use this link which has all works of nostradamus.
Passages which directly refer to India are - centurie 10 , passage 96 and centurie 4 , passage 51 and ONE passage is referring to trouble in east centurie 1, passage 50

Comment: Purely link only answers are not encouraged and allowed on the forum. Do include some content from the book ,  few of    the prophecies mentioned in the book from the link.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Nostradamus 's works are interpreted in different ways , example there is a passage which talks about water on 3 sides , now it can be 3 seas or anything else , so it depends on person's interpretations . However there are 2 passages which directly refer to india , so I will mention them .

Comment: @RaghavGoyal says "I will mention them".  But what is really needed is direct quotations of the relevant passages.  Answers should be self-contained, with links for verification or further details.